# bootstrap collapse event capture

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to change the icon on collapse and facing an event firing issue

The HTML

```
    <div id="collapse-menu" class="row">
        <div class=" panel">
            <a href="#collapse-Content" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#main-menu">
                <h3>A default header<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus pull-right"></span></h3></a>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse-Content" class="collapse">
            Blah Blah! Some Content
        </div>
    </div
```

JS to handle the events

```
$('.row').on('shown.bs.collapse', function(){
    $(this).find(".glyphicon-plus").removeClass("glyphicon-plus").addClass("glyphicon-minus");
});
$('.row').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function(){
    $(this).find(".glyphicon-minus").removeClass("glyphicon-minus").addClass("glyphicon-plus");
});
```

This event is not captured when the collapse is done. I am guessing its fired because the .collapse is removed and the class changed to .in (the default expected behavior).

is this the right event to capture? is the event not triggered on .row?

Comment: Well, i created a fiddle and seems like its catching the trigger.  Fiddle link here: http://jsfiddle.net/BwaaJ/1/

Comment: I also went and made a Fiddle, and it seems to be working fine: http://jsfiddle.net/Z6EXZ/2/

Comment: Double check that you are setting up $('.row').on... after your DOM elements are loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes the HTML is not completely render when you try to attach an event to an element, so you can add your code in the setTimeout function.

```
(function(){

        setTimeout(function(){
            $('.row').on('shown.bs.collapse', function(){
                $(this).find(".glyphicon-plus").removeClass("glyphicon-plus").addClass("glyphicon-minus");
            });
            $('.row').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function(){
                $(this).find(".glyphicon-minus").removeClass("glyphicon-minus").addClass("glyphicon-plus");
            });
        }, 1000);


    });
```

Comment: Shouldn't OP use `$(document).ready(function () {})` instead of a random timeout?